# std::thread-ing a __stdcall method

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-errors

std::thread implementation in msvc-11.0 seems to have problems ignoring calling conventions.

I have the following program :

#### main.cpp

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 # include <thread>

 class foo
 {
 public:
    //intentional __stdcall, breaks compilation
    virtual void __stdcall printOut(const char* str)
    {
       printf("%s", str);
    }
 };

 foo bar;

 int main(void)
 {
    std::thread(&foo::printOut, &bar, "Printing output");
    return 0;
 }
```

Trying to compile the above code with msvc 11.0 (VS2012) throws the following error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
        ...\functional(1152) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type std::_Bind<false,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()(void)'
        with
        [
            _Forced=false,
            _Ret=void,
            _Funx=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _Btuple=std::tuple<foo *,const char *>,
            _Ftuple=std::tuple<>,
            _Fun=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _V0_t=foo *,
            _V1_t=const char (&)[13],
            _V2_t=std::_Nil,
            _V3_t=std::_Nil,
            _V4_t=std::_Nil,
            _V5_t=std::_Nil,
            <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
        ]
        .../xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type std::_Bind<false,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()(void)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Forced=false,
            _Ret=void,
            _Funx=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _Btuple=std::tuple<foo *,const char *>,
            _Ftuple=std::tuple<>,
            _Fun=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _V0_t=foo *,
            _V1_t=const char (&)[13],
            _V2_t=std::_Nil,
            _V3_t=std::_Nil,
            _V4_t=std::_Nil,
            _V5_t=std::_Nil,
            <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
        ]
       ...\thread(52) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Forced=false,
            _Ret=void,
            _Fun=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _V0_t=foo *,
            _V1_t=const char (&)[13],
            _V2_t=std::_Nil,
            _V3_t=std::_Nil,
            _V4_t=std::_Nil,
            _V5_t=std::_Nil,
            <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
        ]
        main.cpp(24) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),foo*,const char(&)[13]>(_Fn,_V0_t &&,_V1_t)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Fn=void (__stdcall foo::* )(const char *),
            _V0_t=foo *,
            _V1_t=const char (&)[13]
        ]
```

Without the __stdcall, this program builds fine. Having or not having a calling convention IMO shouldn't matter to std::thread, but it seems to affect the way this method is interpreted. The compiler seems to have difficulty seeing `printOut(const char*)` as conforming to the definition -- `(foo::* )(const char *)`.

Is this an issue with msvc 11.0 or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm. This now appears like a bug on the compiler's part, that got fixed in 2013.

Comment: Possibly related: [std::mem_fn doesn't work with stdcall](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775554/std-mem-fn-doesnt-work-with-stdcall). Basically, it looks like the compiler requires explicit overloads for all functions that take function pointers, because calling convention is part of the function type. And STL authors failed to provide said overloads, as of VC2012.